# Console Integration Toolkit addEventListener not receiving events in iFramed Visual Force Page

Tags: api, integration, console, cti

I have the following setup (showing a simplified version here):

1. A CTI adapter page (hosted externally under www.example.com or localhost) uses the Console Integration Toolkit to fire an event using fireEvent().
2. A Visual Force page is set up to receive the event using the Console Integration Toolkit addEventListener().

Now, if the Visual Force page is displayed as a tab in the Service Cloud Console, the event is received just fine.

However, if the Visual Force page is **embedded as an iFrame in the externally hosted CTI adapter page**, the **event listener is not called** (although it could be registered without errors).

[image: Picture of the setup]

Can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong or why this is not possible?

---

The externally hosted CTI adapter page looks as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://c.na1.visual.force.com/support/console/31.0/integration.js"></script>
    <title>Event Sender</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#sendEvent").on("click", function () {
                window.sforce.console.fireEvent('TestEvent', 'This is a test event that is sent to a VisualForce page in an iFrame', function (response) {
                    alert("Sending TestEvent resulted in this: " + JSON.stringify(response));
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
  <p><button id="sendEvent">sendEvent()</button></p>
  <iframe src="https://c.cs17.visual.force.com/apex/EventReceiver" width="100%"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

The Visual Force page looks like this:

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" showHeader="false" docType="html-5.0">
      <apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></apex:includeScript>
      <apex:includeScript value="/support/console/31.0/integration.js"/>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
          window.sforce.console.addEventListener('TestEvent', function (event) {
            $("#result").html(JSON.stringify(event));
          });
        });
        </script>
      <h1>Visual Force Page</h1>
      <p>Result: <span id="result"></span></p>
    </apex:page>
```

Comment: i think im running into the this aswell